# Time diff in minutes between 2 dates

Tags: php, datetime

Got this working on php 5.3

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2011-10-10 10:00:00");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2011-10-10 10:45:00");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$hours   = $interval->format('%h'); 
$minutes = $interval->format('%i');
echo 'Diff. in minutes is: '.($hours * 60 + $minutes);
```

How can i make it work on php 5.2 ? are there any equivalent functions available??

**Got it working**

```
$date1 = "2011-10-10 10:00:00";
$date2 = "2011-10-10 10:11:00";
echo round((strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1)) /60);
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Instead of `DateTime` you can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
$datetime1 = strtotime("2011-10-10 10:00:00");
$datetime2 = strtotime("2011-10-10 10:45:00");
$interval  = abs($datetime2 - $datetime1);
$minutes   = round($interval / 60);
echo 'Diff. in minutes is: '.$minutes;
```

Comment: I think that using $interval/60 is best to get the minutes. "date('i',...)" will limit at 59 minutes.

Comment: It is the same solution after my edit and @JaisonErick suggestion. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the minutes spanning several days you could add this one into the mix:

```
$days = $interval->format("%d");

if ($days > 0) {
  return ($hours * 60 + $minutes) + ($days * 24 * 60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function time_Diff_Minutes($startTime, $endTime) {
        $to_time = strtotime($endTime);
        $from_time = strtotime($startTime);
        $minutes = ($to_time - $from_time) / 60; 
        return ($minutes < 0 ? 0 : abs($minutes));   

 } 
 echo time_Diff_Minutes("2008-12-13 20:00:00","2008-12-14 08:00:00"); //output 720
 echo time_Diff_Minutes("2008-12-14 20:00:00","2008-12-13 08:00:00"); //output 0 (startTime > endTime) Ternary will return 0
```