# How to calculate minutes difference between two timestamps in php

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp, difference

Is there any native function for getting the difference between two timestamps? I want to get minutes difference of two timestamps.

Edit: Sorry but actually I just want the difference of two Unix timestamp.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date1_timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
sleep('120');
$date2_timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();

function get_unix_timestamp_minutes_difference($start, $end) {
    /*
        Some code for return the difference between two unix timestamps
    */
}

echo get_timestamp_minutes_difference($date1_timestamp, $date2_timestamp);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculate the difference between 2 timestamps in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905174/calculate-the-difference-between-2-timestamps-in-php)

Comment: $to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:21:00");
echo round(($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929612/time-diff-in-minutes-between-2-dates#7929652

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time diff in minutes between 2 dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929612/time-diff-in-minutes-between-2-dates)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between 2 dates in seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988450/difference-between-2-dates-in-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Carbon class http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ and use his  difference API :http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

Comment: I just checked the link you mentioned and it's really helpful. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$datetime1 = strtotime("2017-05-16 10:00:00");
$datetime2 = strtotime("2017-05-16 10:45:00");
$interval  = abs($datetime2 - $datetime1);
$minutes   = round($interval / 60);
echo 'Diff. in minutes is: '.$minutes;
```